# Strange crash at GoogleMapOptions

Tags: android, crash, maps

I am trying to add a Google map v2 to my activity, but the app crashes as soon as my button listener invokes my Google_Maps() method, this is my button listener:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override 
      public void onClick(View v) {
             Google_Maps(ll);
      }
});
```

And executes this code:

```
public void Google_Maps(LinearLayout ll)
  {
    try 
      { 
        GoogleMapOptions opts = new GoogleMapOptions();
        // Execution never gets here.
      }
    catch (Exception ee)
      {
        // Execution never gets here.
        Log.d("Activi", ee.getMessage());
      }
    // Execution never gets here.
  }
```

The strange thing is that execution never gets to the marked lines. My logcat displays this:

```
05-18 01:23:55.890 : E/AndroidRuntime(11744): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-18 01:23:55.890 : E/AndroidRuntime(11744): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions
05-18 01:23:55.890 : E/AndroidRuntime(11744):     at com.Activi.Euser.activi.Google_Maps(activi.java:2362)
05-18 01:23:55.890 : E/AndroidRuntime(11744):     at com.Activi.Euser.activi$4.run(activi.java:1060)
05-18 01:23:55.890 : E/AndroidRuntime(11744):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-18 01:23:55.890 : E/AndroidRuntime(11744):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-18 01:23:55.890 : E/AndroidRuntime(11744):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-18 01:23:55.890 : E/AndroidRuntime(11744):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
05-18 01:23:55.890 : E/AndroidRuntime(11744):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-18 01:23:55.890 : E/AndroidRuntime(11744):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-18 01:23:55.890 : E/AndroidRuntime(11744):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
05-18 01:23:55.890 : E/AndroidRuntime(11744):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
05-18 01:23:55.890 : E/AndroidRuntime(11744):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-18 01:23:55.890 : E/android.os.Debug(  722): !@Dumpstate > dumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

I am clueless, the application compiles just fine, but as soon as i touch my button, i get a crash. If i remove this line:

```
GoogleMapOptions opts = new GoogleMapOptions();
```

The application doesn't crash, but obviously doesn't do anything. Any ideas what can be wrong? Maybe some libraries are corrupted?

Comment: post the whole stacktrace of the exception. It is unlikely that line is causing your issue

Comment: I added more details, this is what leads me to think something is corrupted....

Comment: what versions of the google play services are you using?

Comment: I am using revision 24. And i am compiling for Android 5.1.1 (API 22).

Comment: Is the Google API Key, that you use valid?

Comment: Yes it is. and my Manifest is correctly formatted, no typos. But to be honest i dont see how a wrong API key could lead to a crash, i could imagine it should handle it more graceful?

Answer (score 0):

If you have in one of your layout files a map fragment:

```
    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/myMapid"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="180dp" />
```

just try to remove this line

```
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

Comment: You mean AndroidManifest.xml? The line is not there.

Comment: No, in your layout files. you have something like this: 
        <fragment
        android:id="@+id/myMapid"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp" />

Comment: I was aiming to do it all programmatically, with no xml layouts. Im close to a beginner though. Any help is very appreciated. This said... no xml layouts yet.

Comment: How looks your dependecies in your build.gradle file?

Comment: It displays Android.jar, android-support-v4.jar and google-play-services.jar as dependencies, Thats it.